# Degrees of freedom in quantum mechanics and $c$-theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In 2D there is notion of degrees of freedom.  D.o.f. defined from correlation functions of stress-enegry tensor:

$$
F(|z|^2) =  z^4 \langle T_{zz}(z,\bar{z}) T_{zz}(0,0) \rangle \\
G (|z|^2) = \frac{z^3 \bar{z}}{4} \langle T_{zz}(z,\bar{z}) T_{z\bar{z}}(0,0) \rangle \\
H(|z|^2) = \frac{z^2 \bar{z}^2}{16} \langle T_{z\bar{z}}(z,\bar{z}) T_{z\bar{z}}(0,0) \rangle .
$$

From this quantites one can define **$C$-function**:
$$
C(|z|^2):= 2F -G - \frac{3}{8}H
$$
$$
r^2 \frac{dC}{dr^2}<0
$$

And this quantity decreases monotonically under two dimmensional RG flow. This is famous [**$c$-theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-theorem). See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237435/). There are also extension of such theorem to 4D, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17117/) post.

Is some analogy of **$C$-function** in quantum mechanics?

About RG in QM see for example [Limit cycles in quantum theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0203088).

Comment: Perhaps a better way would be to look at it from a dilaton effective action point-of-view. Because even in 4d there is no C-function and the a-theorem follows from the effective action.

Comment: Also, another comment is that these things are all related to the trace anomaly, which is proportional to Euler and Weyl densities which are (to the best of my knowledge) only defined in even dimensions. So one could perhaps ask a more general question of the form "degrees of freedom in odd-dimensional CFTs",